# `wstring_convert`std::wstring_convert leads to error C2280: attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement a String class that handle both std::string and std::wstring to reduce conversion code.

In this class I decide to use lazy update strategy.Every time just do modification to the string I need to update.
( If call `operator += (const wchar_t)` then I should update `wstr : wstring` ,If `wstring` isn't correct according to `wstrUpdated:bool` ，then update it with `str:string` by calling `wstring_convert` ,then do the operation.

At This time, `wstring_convert` won't work ,and tell error C2280.)
I'm eager to know what caused this problem.And how can I fix it.

Here's my code:

```
#pragma once
// MutableString.h
#include<string>
#include<codecvt>
#include<locale>

class MutableString
{
public:
    MutableString();
    ~MutableString();

    MutableString(const MutableString& other);
    MutableString(const std::string& other);
    MutableString(const std::string&& other);
    MutableString(const std::wstring& other);
    MutableString(const std::wstring&& other);
    MutableString(const char* other);
    MutableString(const wchar_t* other);

    void clear();

    MutableString& operator = (const MutableString& other);
    MutableString& operator += (const wchar_t ch);
    MutableString& operator += (const char ch);

    std::string getMultiByteString();
    std::wstring getWideString();
private:
    bool strUpdated;
    bool wstrUpdated;
    std::string str;
    std::wstring wstr;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
};

//MutableString.cpp
#include "MutableString.h"


MutableString::MutableString()
{
    str = "";
    wstr = L"";
    strUpdated = false;
    wstrUpdated = false;
}


MutableString::~MutableString()
{
    ;
}
MutableString::MutableString(const MutableString& other)
{
    strUpdated = other.strUpdated;
    wstrUpdated = other.wstrUpdated;
    str = other.str;
    wstr = other.wstr;
}

MutableString::MutableString(const std::string& other)
{
    strUpdated = true; 
    wstrUpdated = false;
    str = other;
}
MutableString::MutableString(const std::string&& other)
{
    strUpdated = true;
    wstrUpdated = false;
    str = other;
}
MutableString::MutableString(const std::wstring& other)
{
    strUpdated = false;
    wstrUpdated = true;
    wstr = other;
}
MutableString::MutableString(const std::wstring&& other)
{
    strUpdated = false;
    wstrUpdated = true;
    wstr = other;
}
MutableString::MutableString(const char* other)
{
    strUpdated = true;
    wstrUpdated = false;
    str = other;
}
MutableString::MutableString(const wchar_t* other)
{
    strUpdated = false;
    wstrUpdated = true;
    wstr = other;
}

void MutableString::clear()
{
    strUpdated = true;
    wstrUpdated = true;
    wstr.clear();
    str.clear();
}

MutableString& MutableString::operator = (const MutableString& other)
{
    str = other.str;
    wstr = other.wstr;
    strUpdated = other.strUpdated;
    wstrUpdated = other.wstrUpdated;
    return *this;
}

MutableString& MutableString::operator += (const wchar_t ch)
{
    if (strUpdated == true)
    {
        if (wstrUpdated == false)
        {
            wstr = converter.from_bytes(str.c_str());
        }
        wstrUpdated = true;
        wstr += ch;
        strUpdated = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (wstrUpdated == true)
        {
            wstr += ch;
            strUpdated = false;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

MutableString& MutableString::operator += (const char ch)
{
    if (wstrUpdated == true)
    {
        if(strUpdated == false)
        {
            str = converter.to_bytes(wstr.c_str());
        }
        strUpdated = true;
        str += ch;
        wstrUpdated = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (strUpdated == true)
        {
            str += ch;
            wstrUpdated = false;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

std::string MutableString::getMultiByteString()
{
    if (strUpdated == false && wstrUpdated == true)
    {
        //change
        strUpdated = true;
        str = converter.to_bytes(wstr.c_str());
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        if (strUpdated == false)
            return
```

Comment: It would help to see the full error, but I would guess `wstring_convert` is not copyable.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes,I made 'wstring_convert' in local code scope instead of class member as you said and it works well. But still confusing.

Comment: `MutableString::MutableString(const std::string&& other)` is pointless. Just get rid of it. You can add `MutableString::MutableString(std::string&& other)`, but you need to learn about move semantics to make good use of it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes you are right. I though that it would make the code safer by adding 'const' in case of "what if I made a mistake and modified the 'std::string&& other' ?" ..but when I come to think about it...even an rvalue is modified won't make effect to anything..